# Hibernate - Pessimistic_Write LockMode not working as expected in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Hibernate 4.2 Pessimistic_Write Lock not behaving properly in Oracle DB while with PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server, it is working as expected.
Any thoughts about it?

Let me put more explanation.

I am getting `StaleObjectException` in the logs.

> StaleObjectException: - "row was updated or deleted by another
>   transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) hibernate"

Hibernate is not able to hold Pessimistic_Write LockMode on Oracle DB, but in other db it is working fine. This is accessed in concurrent mode (multithreaded environment)

Code: -

```
private static final String query1= "select e from EMPLOYEE e join e.addressList address where address in (:addressList) order by e.streetName,e.createdOn";

Query query = getSession().createQuery(query1).setLockOptions(new LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE));
```

Comment: "not behaving properly"  - and we are supposed to know what that means?  Please show as [mcve].

Comment: Let me know if you need any more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with how Hibernate handles Pessimistic write locks in Oracle. 
Whenever you perform a Pessimistic lock to lock a row, other databases fires a single query to obtain the row and lock the row so that the loaded records cannot be modified by other transactions. This is handled differently
By Hibernate in case of Oracle. In case of Oracle, it fires two queries one to load the records and another to lock the loaded records using “SELECT FOR UPDATE” clause. Now the issue is that the two sql statements, generated by Hibernate for Oracle, is not atomic and not controlled by a lock, hence internally the single query that we fire translates into two Queries. Since these two queries are not atomic if two thread fires our query then both of these load the same record without locking.
After this the first thread acquires the lock (which second thread has already loaded) and updates it. Now when second thread tries to acquire the lock for a record which it has already loaded it detects a change as the first thread has updated it and hence
Throws a Stale Object exception. Since this is a issue with the core Hibernate platform we cannot fix the root cause of this defect.

We find one workaround for this. To fix this issue we have introduced a workaround to lock another table through Pessimistic write before firing the actual query. This would make sure that the thread locking behavior works correctly at the expense of a small increase (few milliseconds) in response time.